# Simple shopping cart with html only

Tags: html

I am just asking if it is possible to do a simple shopping cart with HTML ONLY! If it is possible, can anyone show me how to start it and using what method to do it?

Comment: HTML is markup, not a programming language. At the very least you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, i am just curious to know if it is possible. Now i know it is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html**- is a mark up language and its only for designing web pages-called front end.

**Javascript**(Not java)- JavaScript is a client-side scripting language, which means the source code is processed by the client's web browser rather than on the web server. This means JavaScript functions can run after a webpage has loaded without communicating with the server. For example, a JavaScript function may check a web form before it is submitted to make sure all the required fields have been filled out. The JavaScript code can produce an error message before any information is actually transmitted to the server.

Simply doing some validation,calculation, etc..in our PC

**PHP**-  is a server-side scripting language designed for web development but also used as a general-purpose programming language.PHP code can be simply mixed with HTML code, or it can be used in combination with various templating engines and web frameworks. PHP code is usually processed by a PHP interpreter, which is usually implemented as a web server's native module or a Common Gateway Interface (CGI) executable. After the PHP code is interpreted and executed, the web server sends the resulting output to its client, usually in the form of a part of the generated web page; for example, PHP code can generate a web page's HTML code, an image, or some other data. PHP has also evolved to include a command-line interface (CLI) capability and can be used in standalone graphical applications

**Database**- is just a collection of data. 
A little analogy may help make it clearer why we use specialised database software. Think about the documents stored on your computer. If you were to save all your documents using a (brain-dead) file naming scheme like "1.doc", "2.doc", "3.doc", ... "9,999,999.doc" (etc), you will eventually face a problem of finding the right file if you're looking for a specific document. For example, if you're looking for a business proposal you made some time ago to XYZ Company, which file should you open? One way is to sequentially check every single file, starting from "1.doc", till you get the right data. But this is obviously a highly inefficient method of getting the right file. And it's primarily the result of an inefficient method of storing your data (ie, saving your files) in the first place.

eg:-MySql,Wamp,Apachae etc

And even more like jquery ajax (if want)...
You cant make a website without the help of these languages

If you are a fresher this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com) will helps you.

Regds

Answer (score 1):

When you say only html is without backend?

If is that see this -> [How do I store a simple cart using localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554456/how-do-i-store-a-simple-cart-using-localstorage)

Comment: `Window.localStorage` is a browser provided API that can be accessed with JavaScript. It is not HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API